# create a column that is a sum of two other columns in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**Background**

I am using [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) to fetch data from an api and display it. 
I want to add a column on the fly that is a sum of two other columns.
For instance say i want to create a column called "random" that adds up data from
column confirmed and death how would i do it?

**HTML CODE**

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
    <div id="loadingLabel">Loading...</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
const getNewCases = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020');
  const data = await response.json();
  let usa = data.filter(val => {
    return val.countryRegion === 'US';
  });
  $('#loadingLabel').hide();
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: usa,
    bLengthChange: false,
    bPaginate: false,
    scrollY:        '50vh',
    columns: [
      { data: 'provinceState', title: 'State' },
      { data: 'countryRegion', title: 'Country' },
      { data: 'lastUpdate', title: 'Last Update' },
      { data: 'confirmed', title: 'Confirmed' },
      { data: 'deaths', title: 'Deaths' },
      { data: 'recovered', title: 'Recovered' }
    ]
  });
};
getNewCases();
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x3742vrn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would recommend to make use of DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to avoid further issues with asynchronously fetched data.

To solve your major problem simply add another column definition and make use of [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#function) option with a function as parameter:

```js
$('#myTable').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020',
    dataSrc: d => d.filter(entry => entry.countryRegion == 'US')
  },
  bLengthChange: false,
  bPaginate: false,
  scrollY:        '50vh',
  columns: [
    { data: 'provinceState', title: 'State' },
    { data: 'countryRegion', title: 'Country' },
    { data: 'lastUpdate', title: 'Last Update' },
    { data: 'confirmed', title: 'Confirmed' },
    { data: 'deaths', title: 'Deaths' },
    { data: 'recovered', title: 'Recovered' },
    { data: ({confirmed,deaths}) => Number(confirmed)+Number(deaths), title: 'Random' }
  ]
})
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script> </head><body><table id="myTable"></table></body></html>
```

Comment: is there any way to make this responsive for a phone screen?

Answer (score 1):

Just add column new to columns attribute with render method u can make math options with another columns

```
 {data:null,
            title: "random",
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                return parseInt( data.deaths) + parseInt(data.recovered);
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scxh3ktg/